# PHP-FPM - Create a pool with restricted filesystem access

Tags: php, linux

In a hosting environment, I want the users to be able to do everything that php offers, but only within their own folders.

For example...

DocumentRoot for mySite.se is: /var/www/html/mySite.se

I don't want it to be possible for the owner of mySite.se to type "shell_exec("cd / && dir") and get a list of the entire root system.

In other words, "shell_exec("cd / && dir") should either return the directory list of "DocumentRoot" for mySite.se or nothing at all.

I've found some information online and it seems that what I want to achieve can be arranged with php-fpm, but I'm not quite sure how.

At the moment, my php-fpm setup works with two different domains/virtual hosts. So there is no problem there. The problem is that I don't really know how to restrict the users to their own folders when they use functions like shell_exec

Pool conf:

```
[mySite.se]
user = testsite
group = testsite
listen = /var/run/php/php8.2-fpm-mySite.se.sock
listen.owner = testsite
listen.group = testsite
php_admin_value[disable_functions] = exec,passthru,system
php_admin_flag[allow_url_fopen] = off
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
chdir = /
```

vHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName mySite.se
     ServerAlias www.mySite.se
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mySite.se

     <Directory /var/www/html/mySite.se>
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
     </Directory>

     <FilesMatch ".php$"> 
         SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm-mySite.se.sock|fcgi://localhost/"          
      </FilesMatch>
 
      ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
      CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined  
</VirtualHost>
```

Right now I use "testsite" as user and group in the pool configuration. I experimented with group and user permissions in linux but can't get the result I want

Comment: 'Everything that PHP offers" is dangerous enough. If you include `shell-exec` that extends to potentially anything that is available on the machine. Do you really want your users to have that much freedom?